# How to create a collection of fields from two Django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to create a custom user registration form in Django 1.8.3. The thing I want to achieve is a form that consists of two separate forms based on two separate models. The first model is the default Django `User` model and the form based on it contains `username`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password1` and `password2` fields. The second model is `UserDetails` and for now it contains only three fields - `user` (which should store a foreign key - user id), `middle_name` and `phone_number`.  I would like to create a template that will display fields of these two forms in following order:

- `username`,
- `email`,
- `phone_number`,
- `first_name`,
- `middle_name`,
- `last_name`,
- `password1`,
- `password2`.

The question is: Is there any way to create a list (or any other collection) of those fields which I could later iterate over to make them displayed in this particular order? I tried to create instances of my forms:

```
registration_form = RegistrationForm()
user_details_form = UserDetailsForm()
```

and a list of their fields in my custom order:

```
fields = [registration_form.username, 
          registration_form.email, 
          user_details_form.phone_number,
          registration_form.first_name,
          ...]
```

Then I tried to display fields in HTML file using following code:

```
{% for field in fields %}
    {{ field }}
    {{ field.help_text }}
    {{ field.errors }}
{% endfor %}
```

but it didn't work - I got the following error:

> AttributeError at /register 'RegistrationForm' object has no attribute
>   'username'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply combine two forms using django's `ModelForm`.

What you can do instead is extend `RegistrationForm` class by adding custom user fields from `UserDetails` model. Then override all needed methods (`clean`, `save`, etc) to include those custom fields in your flow.

To reorder the fields, you need to extend/override `Meta` class inside the new form class.

Example:

```
class UserDetailsForm(RegistrationForm):
    middle_name = ...
    phone_number = ...

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', ..., 'password2')
```

I'm assuming your `RegistrationForm` form is based on django's `ModelForm`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I understand that my approach was wrong (because I wanted to stick to one-to-one model-form dependence, although it was not necessary). Extending my form class is certainly a better idea.